# Printing Page Numbers in Okular

Tags: printing, kde, okular

I'm using Okular to print some PDF files.
How can I add page number to each page?

**Edit**:
Screen shots that Lucio requested:
(I have no print menu! I have File > Print >> Options)
[image: Pages Tab]

Comment: In the print menu go to the Options label and tell me what do you see. If you can, make a shoot-screen.

Comment: @Lucio: I added the screenshots

Comment: @Lucio: In Options Tab I only have "Duplex Printing" & "Color Mode"; anyhow I added its screenshot too

Comment: You're right, in the Options label it's not the option. Delete the first and second screenshoot if you can. What options appear if you do click in --Options->Pages label->Banner Pages section->Start (above End) where it says 'none'-- tell me What options gives to you?

Comment: @Lucio: Banner Pages has these: Standard, Unclassified, Confidential, Classified, Secret, Top Secret !

Comment: No, there is nothing. What about Page Border? The only options that gives to you is a frame?

Comment: @Lucio: Single Line, Single Tick Line, Double Line, Double Tick Line !!

Comment: It'd also be nice if people answered what "Page Label" text input box does.

Comment: @RYN has this problem been solved with the April 2017 update of `Okular`?  https://okular.kde.org/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't have this update currently; I will update and test & then I will answer here but about my problem I solved it with ‍`pdftk`